# angularjs broadcast changes to an object in a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose I have a service that returns an object with a few values.  This is my settings object.  I use this service in `controller 1` to get the values from the object and assign it to the `$scope`.  In `controller2` I use the same service to add a few more values to the object.  Now I need `controller1` to realize that those changes have been made and update the `$scope` accordingly.

I tried using `$watch` in `controller1` like so

```
$scope.$watch(myservice.settings, function(oldvalue,newvalue) {
    console.log(newvalue);
});
```

But it seems that the digest cycle isn't run when the object is updated in controller2.  Apart from manually running the `$digest` cycle, which as I understand it is generally bad parctice, how else can I get the functionaliy I'm looking for?

Comment: This is _exactly_ how a service should be used, so your errors don't seem to make sense to me. Do you have a JSFiddle or a Plunkr demonstrating this side effect?

Comment: `$watch` expects an expression or a function that returns a value. Is this a mistranslation or have you not wrapped `myservice.settings` in quotes?

Comment: myservice.settings is a reference to an object

Comment: Yes, but $watch doesn't accept an object as an argument - it accepts a string (expression) or a function. e.g. `$scope.$watch('myservice.settings', function(){...})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) accepts a function which returns a value or a string to be evaluated as an expression:

It also will not handle internal comparison for objects unless you pass `true` as a third argument:

```
$scope.$watch('myservice.settings', function(oldvalue,newvalue) {
    console.log(newvalue);
}, true);
```

This will perform a deep comparison using [`angular.equals`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals) instead of comparing for reference equality, which is the default. If you need to perform only a shallow comparison (ie your object is only one level deep), you can use [`$watchCollection`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watchCollection) instead:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('myservice.settings', function(oldvalue,newvalue) {
    console.log(newvalue);
});
```

The advantage of `$watchCollection` over `$watch(func, func, true)` is that it is less expensive.

Comment: So just to make sure I understand completely, $watch receives a function or a string, it cannot directly receive a reference to an object?

Comment: Yes, but the string is meant to be an expression to be evaluated. Meaning if you wrap the object name in quotes, the evaluation will produce the reference to the object. And sorry, I just realized that I'd failed to wrap my sample code with quotes as I'd suggested you do.

Comment: That was it!  Thanks, I was reading through the documentation, but I must have missed those couple of details